# Async() vs threading on performance and control

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous

I am watching [GoingNative 2012 Day 1 talk "C++11 style" by Bjarne Stroustrup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m0H5bUPfwn8) , since 1:05:13 he seems was promoting `async()` than threading.

I do wonder, now 4 years passed, in C++ world, what's the pros and cons of `async()` vs threading, in terms of performance and control?

There're different opinions that I got lost:

For example, on performance: 
one SO post [C++11 thread vs async performance (VS2013)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26730287/c11-thread-vs-async-performance-vs2013) says creating a thread is expensive ("200 000 CPU cycles in Windows OS") but `async()` will utilize thread pool so cheaper; but another SO post [Will async(launch::async) in C++11 make thread pools obsolete for avoiding expensive thread creation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351352/will-asynclaunchasync-in-c11-make-thread-pools-obsolete-for-avoiding-expen) don't think so ("OSes have a lot of reasons they should be making thread creation as cheap as possible")

On control, previously my impression is threading allows more control; but an SO post [async vs threading, when to use each option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790683/async-vs-threading-when-to-use-each-option) on C# says "Threads have SOME Advantages when yo uneed control over the low Level thread Parameters - which is VERY rare. "

Also, I suppose the performance / control depends deeply on the implementation. So I wonder, 4 years after Bjarne promoting `async()`, how is it doing in C++ world, comparing with threading, in terms of performance and control?

Comment: "`async()` will utilize thread pool so cheaper" only on windows platform or everywhere - the thread pool?

Comment: Like most of everything else, it *depends*. What is the purpose of the thread? Is it supposed to be a long-living thread to e.g. handle network connections? Is it just doing some calculations and returning a result? For a long-running thread, the hit on performance for creating a thread is negligible, for a short-lived calculate-and-return-result thread, it might be considerate.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg any numbers?

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal my impression is on all , but depends on implementation of compiler and OS

Comment: http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3780.pdf

Comment: @HansPassant thx, so this is an update at 2013 Sept...

Comment: Yeah, that shiny toy did not last long.  A bit dangerous to comment on this as an outsider.  Afaik this feature pretty much requires a work-stealing threadpool to be effective.  Microsoft did, Tony Williams didn't.  They could not get a consensus on how to deal with thread-local storage and that killed it.  Pretty remarkable that this wasn't thought through before they added it to the standard so there is probably more to it.

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry for my ignorant, who is Tony Williams?

Comment: He's the pope of Unix and Boost threading and an influential committee member.  Wrote "C++ Concurrency in Action".